# How do I assign multiple values to object property with for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign the `name` property of `obj` the `[i][0]` indices of `sampleArr`.  `Console.log(arr[i][0])` outputs `"animals", "sopranos", "guitars"` with each iteration. However, obj.name = arr[i][0] will only assign `obj.name = "guitars"`.

What explains this behavior, and how could I assign these multiple elements to a single property within a loop?

```
var sampleArr = [
    ["animals", ["dogs", "cats", "pigs"]],
    ["sopranos", ["Tony", "Carmella", "AJ", "Meadow"]],
    ["guitars", ["Stratocaster", "Telecaster", "Gibson Flying-V"]]
];


function objectifier(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i][0])
    obj.name = arr[i][0]
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: What is the end result data structure that you want?

Comment: Try `obj["name"] = arr[i][0]`

Comment: name: "animals", "sopranos", "guitars"

Comment: So you should use `obj.name = []` and then `obj.name.push(arr[i][0])`

Comment: @nurdyguy same result

Comment: Yeah, you only get the "guitars" because you are re-assigning it every time.  You need to create the array and append like jonzee says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
obj.name = arr[i][0]
```

with

```
obj[i] = {};
obj[i]["name"] = arr[i][0];
```

Comment: `"TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined.`
Is it not possible to create the name property with bracket notation as  
`obj.name =`  does...

Comment: Yes. It was replaced verbatim

Comment: Correction. omitted first line.

Comment: It threw only when ob[i] = {} was ommitted, and / or declared outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

> how could I assign these multiple elements to a single property within
>   a loop?

To achieve this you have to keep array in this single property, like this:

```
function objectifier(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i][0])
    obj.name.push(arr[i][0]);
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: End structure should be `name: "animals", "sopranos", "guitars"`

Comment: This fulfills the quoted criteria but I'm looking for that specific structure